# xmgrace: Plot boundary for a data set

Tags: xmgrace

I have a data set in XY format. About 25mn lines of data. All I care about is the boundary of this dataset. Is it possible to somehow extract this feature on XMGrace directly?

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean by `boundary` of the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about calculating the [convex hull](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexHull.html) of your data points. No, this is not possible in xmgrace directly but you could use a program such as [qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) to prepare a file that can be plotted in xmgrace or some other plotter.